# c# winform - using timer to animate drop down menu

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make an animated drop down menu in winforms.  The form would expand when there is a mouse_enter event and contract back to original size when there is a mouse_leave event. I use a timer to control the rate of "animation" to achieve the desired result.

upon running the first few times, the "animation" is according to what i want but after a few loops (mouse in -> mouse out - > mouse in -> mouse out -> etc), the animation starts to speed up until it reaches a point where it would just simply appear/disappear at a fast speed.

are there alternatives to achieve this effect or maintain the desired rate of animation?

btw, this is my first question here so do advise me if I broke any rules/formats etc!

```
    private void setForm()
    {
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width - this.Width, Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height - this.Height);
    }

    Timer Timer1;
    bool mode = false;

    private void B00nZPictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mode = true;

        Timer1 = new Timer();
        Timer1.Interval = 10;
        Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
        Timer1.Start();
    }

    private void B00nZ_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mode = false;

        Timer1 = new Timer();
        Timer1.Interval = 10;
        Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
        Timer1.Start();
    }

    void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;

        if (mode)
        {
            if (this.Height < temp)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height + 35);
            }
            else if (this.Height > temp)
            {
                if (this.Height - temp > 10)
                {
                    this.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height - 3);
                }
                else if (this.Height - temp > 0)
                {
                    this.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height - 1);
                }
            }
            else if (this.Height == temp)
            {
                Timer1.Stop();
                Timer1.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Height > B00nZPictureBox.Height)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height - 35);
            }
            else if (this.Height - B00nZPictureBox.Height <= B00nZPictureBox.Height)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Width, B00nZPictureBox.Height);
            }

            if (this.Height == B00nZPictureBox.Height)
            {
                Timer1.Stop();
                Timer1.Dispose();
            }
        }

        setForm();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with a global variable being changed after every iteration.  Can you share some relevant code with us (the timer tick code for instance) so we can help you debug this?

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply, I did declare the timer as a global variable and a boolean flag to keep track of the expand/contract menu. I hope i did use the timer correctly..

Comment: The code really helps us understand.  BTW, welcome to SO.  You are doing a good job.  Just remember when you are asking questions to look at it from our perspective.  We need the information (especially the relevant code) to solve the issue.  Too little information means we probably can't solve the issue and too much information means we have to wade through too much so we might get lost or not even try.

Comment: Disappointing answer mark.  Do you know *why* it worked and your version didn't?  Very important if you want to get ahead in .NET programming, you'll make the same mistake again otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what you want to do, here is what I would do.  First, create two timers.  Call one enterTimer and the other leaveTimer.  Hook up their event handlers once (in the setup code like on form_load).  Set their intervals also but don't start them.  Then, when the Mouse enters, start the enterTimer.  When the mouse leaves, start the leaveTimer.

You could play around with waiting until the enterTimer ends before firing the leaveTimer or something like that depending on what you want your logic to be.  You could also stop the currently-running timer when another timer is triggered.

It would look something like this:

```
    //This would be your FormLoad event or somewhere else where you initialize your form information
    private void form_load()
    {
        enterTimer.Interval = 10;
        enterTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(enterTimer_Tick);
        leaveTimer.Interval = 10;
        leaveTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(leaveTimer_Tick);
    }

    private void setForm()
    {
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width - this.Width, Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height - this.Height);
    }

    Timer enterTimer;
    Timer leaveTimer;

    private void B00nZPictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enterTimer.Start();
    }

    private void B00nZ_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        leaveTimer.Start();
    }

    void enterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Put your enter logic here
    }

    void leaveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Put your leave logic here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you open the menu you're adding an EventHandler.  When the timer goes off, it's executing your handler multiple times.

Either add the handler once, or remove it each time the menu closes.

Comment: I am kinda new to this event driven programming, so pardon any noob questions.. i dont think removing it each time the menu closes works cause I anticipate the there may be a mouse leave event even before the menu loads finish. so in order to add the handler once I have to separate into 2 different timers, one for expanding and another for contracting?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make just one Timer, when the Form loads, and hook the event handler up once.  Thereafter you should merely enable and disable the timer, without disposing or re-creating it.

Right now if you enter and leave before the menu fully expands, you end up leaking a timer -- it's been started, but the global variable has since been changed to a brand new timer, so you have no way of stopping or disposing the old one.

Comment: just something i was pondering.. is there something similar to java's system.gc() where i could call in C# to get rid of this so called leaking timer?

Comment: @user776914: `GC.Collect` is the equivalent, but timers which are running are not eligible for collection.  The garbage collector is not a cure-all for leaks.  Event subscriptions are another common way to have an object still be reachable (it's in the event's handler list) but there's no way for your program to recover a handle to it (only the object generating the events can read its own handler list).  Best is to avoid unnecessary creation of timers.